# Bouncy Castle DoFinal returning byte array but string is not correct

Tags: c#, cryptography, bouncycastle

I am having an issue decrypting, currently the output returns a byte array, but when I attempt to convert it to a string via either base64, UTF8, Ascii, or Unicode, the string is just gibberish, created a private and public key using openssl and used that to generate the keypair, any suggestion on where to look would be helpful, using this as my foundation,also the private key from this git repo test classes seem to work fine in decrypting, for example, this private key seems to work fine.

> "MIGHAgEAMBMGByqGSM49AgEGCCqGSM49AwEHBG0wawIBAQQgCPSuFr4iSIaQprjj" + "chHPyDu2NXFe0vDBoTpPkYaK9dehRANCAATnaFz/vQKuO90pxsINyVNWojabHfbx" + "9qIJ6uD7Q7ZSxmtyo/Ez3/o2kDT8g0pIdyVIYktCsq65VoQIDWSh2Bdm"

But this ones that I generated doesn't.

> ME0CAQAwEwYHKoZIzj0CAQYIKoZIzj0DAQcEMzAxAgEBBCAn0M1F8ej/KhDm2VpEJZtMXGRpwa73m5k3J/D+5Va9RaAKBggqhkjOPQMBBw==

```
open ssl to generate keys:
privatekey:
openssl pkcs8 -topk8 -inform PEM -outform DER -in key.pem -nocrypt | base64 | paste -sd "\0" -

publickey:
openssl ec -in key.pem -pubout -text -noout 2> /dev/null | grep "pub:" -A5 | sed 1d | xxd -r -p | base64 | paste -sd "\0" -
```

https://github.com/chengbo/ApplePayAndroidPayDecryption/blob/master/Decryption/TokenDecrypter.cs

```
KeyParameter keyparam = ParameterUtilities.CreateKeyParameter("AES", encryptionKeyBytes);
ParametersWithIV parameters = new ParametersWithIV(keyparam, symmetricIv);
IBufferedCipher cipher = GetCipher();

cipher.Init(false, parameters);
try
{  
    output = cipher.DoFinal(cipherData);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    throw new ApplicationException("Invalid Data", ex);
}
```

Comment: I can't figure you what your objective is.  You might update the question to tell what you're trying to do, and then describe where your attempt goes wrong.  I.e., show us the output that isn't as expected, and tell us what you expected it to be.

Answer (score -1):

public static class AESHelper
    {

```
    public static string Encrypt(string plaintext, string key, string vector)
    {
        return Encrypt(plaintext, key, Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(vector));
    }

    public static string Encrypt(string plaintext, string key, byte[] vector)
    {
        return Convert.ToBase64String(Encrypt(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(plaintext), key, vector));
    }

    public static byte[] Encrypt(byte[] plaintext, string key, byte[] vector)
    {
        using (var rijndael = new RijndaelManaged() { Key = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(key), Mode = CipherMode.CBC, Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7, IV = vector })
        using (var encryptor = rijndael.CreateEncryptor())
        {
            var resultArray = encryptor.TransformFinalBlock(plaintext, 0, plaintext.Length);
            return resultArray;
        }
    }

    public static string Decrypt(string ciphertext, string key, string vector)
    {
        return Decrypt(ciphertext, key, Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(vector));
    }

    public static string Decrypt(string ciphertext, string key, byte[] vector)
    {
        return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Decrypt(Convert.FromBase64String(ciphertext), key, vector));
    }

    public static byte[] Decrypt(byte[] ciphertext, string key, byte[] vector)
    {
        using (var rijndael = new RijndaelManaged() { Key = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(key), Mode = CipherMode.CBC, Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7, IV = vector })
        using (var decryptor = rijndael.CreateDecryptor())
        {
            var resultArray = decryptor.TransformFinalBlock(ciphertext, 0, ciphertext.Length);
            return resultArray;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: could you please explain a bit? I understand in my situationI would use byte[] decrypt and pass in the ciphertest and intialization vector, but I have a few questions

Comment: 1. currently I have IV set to this  symmetricIv = Hex.Decode("00000000000000000000000000000000"); is this the correct initializarion vector for CRT/No padding?

Comment: 2. what key is being passed into string key? private?public?sharedsecret?

Comment: dotnet core not implement CTR mode，you can use https://www.nuget.org/packages/ChilkatDnCore/